# Echo file contents inside params array

Tags: php

I'm trying to finish creating a php keygen for my product.

Is it possible for me to echo a text value inside on array (specifically the HWID which is taken from an uploaded text file)?

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('text.txt');

$params = array(
    hwid => "echo $file;", // Exactly as returned by VMProtectGetCurrentHWID
    user_data => base64_decode("CGCvRvMWcPHGdMjQ"), // string of bytes
    );
?>
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: First of all you should single quote the keys, else they are expected being a valid constant.

Comment: Can you please explain `echo a text value inside on array`?

Comment: The hardware id will come from a file I upload named "text.txt" - I want to be able to enter the contents from that text document into the hwid array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to echo just do this:

```php
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('text.txt');

$params = array(
    hwid => $file, // Exactly as returned by VMProtectGetCurrentHWID
    user_data => base64_decode("CGCvRvMWcPHGdMjQ"), // string of bytes
);
```

Comment: thanks! I did try this at the very start and nothing worked.. clearly I was a bit delirious at 2am.